# Turning a 2D array into a tree

Tags: javascript, array, tree

I have the following data structure that's obtained from a third party:

```
var data = [
    ["Parent1", "Parent1.1", "Parent1.1.1"],
    ["Parent2", "Parent2.1", "Parent2.1.1"],
    ["Parent3", "Parent3.1", "Parent3.1.1"],
    ["Parent1", "Parent1.2", "Parent1.2.1"],
    ["Parent1", "Parent1.2", "Parent1.2.2"]
];
```

Where child nodes may or may not be present.
I'm turning it into a tree to represent the data logically:

```
var tree = {
    "Parent1": {
        "Parent1.1": ["Parent1.1.1"],
        "Parent1.2": ["Parent1.2.1", "Parent1.2.2"]
    },
    "Parent2": {
        "Parent2.1": ["Parent2.1.1"]
    },
    "Parent3": {
        "Parent3.1": ["Parent3.1.1"]
    }
};
```

What I'm currently doing seems rather straightforward to myself, but somewhat convoluted due to the numerous return statements:

```
var tree = data.reduce(function(tree, item) {
    if (!item[0]) return tree;
    tree[item[0]] = tree[item[0]] || {};
    if (!item[1]) return tree;
    tree[item[0]][item[1]] = tree[item[0]][item[1]] || [];
    if (!item[2]) return tree;
    tree[item[0]][item[1]].push(item[2]);
    return tree;
}, {}); //Returns as shown above
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem, what improvements could be made?
The depth of the data is always fixed at three.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing similar issue where I needed to convert the 2-D array to a tree structure. This code might help.:)

```
var tree = data.reduce(function(tree, item) {
    var tempTree = tree;
    for(var i=0;i<item.length;i++){
        if(!tempTree[item[i]])
            tempTree[item[i]] = {};
        tempTree = tempTree[item[i]];
    }
    return tree;
}, {});
```